# How to get a Method from a spring RequestMapping annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

I write my controllers and request mappings as

Code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController1
{

    @RequestMapping("abc.do")
    @RequestBody
    public String doAbc()
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

I want to write a method so that it takes the request mapping string as input and returns the Method to call. How can I do this? Thanks.

Some of you may think all this is nonsense and I agree it is. Just that we have moved all the web code to "ajax" and still have code for the mobile interface that is non-ajax. So I need some kind of temporary glue-code that will make all this work till we 'ajaxify' the mobile interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. If you want to accept a part of the URI as a parameter in your method, see the following code.

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    @RequestMapping("/abc/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String doAbc(@PathVariable("id") String abcId){
        ...
    }
}
```